# Objective C - get root permission in cocoa app for modifying system file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, authorization, macos-high-sierra

I am going to create / update file in system directory in High Sierra version 10.13.4.

For it, should get root permission of mac os.
I tried to launch privileged process with this code .

```
OSStatus LaunchPrivilegedProcess(NSString *path) {

    OSStatus status;
    AuthorizationRef authorizationRef;

    status = AuthorizationCreate(NULL, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment,
                                 kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, &authorizationRef);

    if (status != errAuthorizationSuccess)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error Creating Initial Authorization: %d", status);
        return status;
    }


    AuthorizationItem right = {kAuthorizationRightExecute, 0, NULL, 0};
    AuthorizationRights rights = {1, &right};
    AuthorizationFlags flags = kAuthorizationFlagDefaults |
    kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed |
    kAuthorizationFlagPreAuthorize |
    kAuthorizationFlagExtendRights;

    status = AuthorizationCopyRights(authorizationRef, &rights, NULL, flags, NULL);
    if (status != errAuthorizationSuccess)
    {
        NSLog(@"Copy Rights Unsuccessful: %d", status);
        return status;
    }


    char *tool = path.UTF8String;
    char *args[] = {NULL};
    FILE *pipe = NULL;

    status = AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges(authorizationRef, tool,
                                                kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, args, &pipe);
    if (status != errAuthorizationSuccess)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %d", status);
        return status;
    }

    status = AuthorizationFree(authorizationRef, kAuthorizationFlagDestroyRights);

    return status;
}
```

But it fails in `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges` with Error code: -60031 (`errAuthorizationToolExecuteFailure`).

How can I solve this issue?

Is there any other way to get root permission to update System files?

Comment: This is the path what I want to override; /System/Library/Displays/Contents/Resources/Overrides

Comment: `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges` is deprecated you have to use `SMJobBless`.

Comment: thank you @bikram990 SMJobBless is also old one. Would you give me good example?

Comment: The SMJobBless example might be old-ish, but it's still the current recommended method for installing a root-privilege service.

Comment: Also, you didn't say *what* system file you want to modify. SIP will prevent most system files from being modified, even if you have root privileges.

Comment: @JamesBucanek thank you for your comment. I downloaded SMJobBless source code from Apple Developer site. I am going to create custom resolution in `/System/Library/Displays/Contents/Resources/Overrides/`. But I am not sure what I have to do by using SMJobBless. How can I set the path in SMJobBless? Please let me know what to do. Best regards

Comment: `SMJobBless` simply lets you create a helper program (a faceless, POSIX, executable) that you can send and receive messages to via XPC. The helper process runs with root privileges, so you isolate the code you need to run with root privileges and compile that in your helper app, and then trigger it using an XPC message handler. What that code does, and why, is entirely up to you.